# complexity of recursive permutation function

Tags: algorithm, recursion, complexity-theory

I have a recursive function in which the subfunctions/operations have the following complexities:

1. (n-1)!
2. (n-1)
3. O(n-1)
4. O(log((n-1)!)) + O(n)

I want to know the asymptotic complexity for the whole function. How do I do this?

Comment: the whole will be the worst of the components'.

Comment: How is your recusion? T(n) = T(n-1) + (1.) + (2.) + (3.) + (4.)?

Comment: T(n) = T(n-1) + (n-1)(n-1)!O(n-1)O(log((n-1)!)) + O(n)

Comment: The recursion you just gave is radically different from your original description, as well as the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may help you :

```
f1(x) = O(g1)
f2(x) = O(g2)
=> f1+f2 = O(max(g1, g2))
```

So you can say that the complexity of summation of functions, is equal to the order of computation for the one that has the biggest.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you use recurrence relations, see e.g.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation

For case 2 & 3 you'll end up with O(n^2), for case 1 & 4, I'm not sure without doing the actual math.